# How can i change tagname which has childs?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, tagname

In php I have a xml file. I ask for choosing a node by using domdocument object in my file then changing its name.For example I want to change invite tag.But I can't.How can I solve my problem?

```html
<library>
  <data a:foo="1" x="bar" xmlns:a="http://example.com/a">
    <invite>
      <username>jmansa</username>
      <userid>1</userid>
    </invite>
    <update>1</update>
  </data>
</library>
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem.